# TemplateDoesNotExist at /(Routing issue with django)

Tags: python, routes, django-views, django-templates

I want to make a simple blog app that I found on some tutorial but I seem to have stopped at this step where I'm trying to post a simple template for my main page of the website.

I know this is a well-known issue seen in django s paradigm but I simply don't know what else to do.

I moved the 'templates' folder over the main directory folder, back to the app folder, back and forth;
I made sure the name of the files are correct as in the paths I specified;
I made sure I mentioned the name of the app at INSTALLED_APPS to make sure django would load the app's template

All I'm getting in return is:

> Request Method:   GET
>   Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
>   Django Version: 3.0.2
>   Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
>   Exception Value:
>   blog/home.html

Here is my *INSTALLED_APPS* section of settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
```

My *TEMPLATES*

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

And finally the *views.py* from the app

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request,'blog/home.html')
```

Comment: Where exactly did you locate your template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. I forgot to share it.

```
C:.
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│
├───blog
│   │   admin.py
│   │   apps.py
│   │   models.py
│   │   tests.py
│   │   urls.py
│   │   views.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───migrations
│   │   │   __init__.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   │
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───blog
│   │           home.html
│   │
│   └───__pycache__
│           admin.cpython-38.pyc
│           apps.cpython-38.pyc
│           models.cpython-38.pyc
│           urls.cpython-38.pyc
│           views.cpython-38.pyc
│           __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│
└───django_project
    │   asgi.py
    │   settings.py
    │   urls.py
    │   wsgi.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───__pycache__
            settings.cpython-38.pyc
            urls.cpython-38.pyc
            wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
            __init__.cpython-38.pyc
```

//L.E: As it turns out, I did everything right except that I didn't know django doesn't like to self-update after every edit I did on the files of the app.
I did close the app and re-started it few times and without restarting my machine. 
For some unknown reason it worked fine after a few hours of inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

A TemplateDoesNotExist error suggests that it can't find blog/home.html in the templates folder.

If this isn't the case could you provide some more details on the folder structure ?

should be something like this

```
my_blog_project
 - manage.py
 - blog_app
  -- urls.py
  -- views.py etc...
 - templates
  -- blog
    --- home.html
```